# adminId not saving in user table in a one to one relationship springboot

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have mapped a one to many relationship between a user and an admin as shown in the user class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long timestamp;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "adminId")
    Admin admin;
```

Now I am trying to save a user by inserting a value of 1 to the adminId field in the users table using SessionFactory of hibernate as shown

```
public void save(User user) {

        //User userAdmin = new User();
        long id = 1 ;
        user.setId(id);

        getSession().save(user);
    }
```

**EDITTED**

Considering getters and setters, these are the fields in the admin table

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "adminId")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String department;
```

My challenge is that when I save, nothing gets inserted **(that is value of 1)** on the adminId field referencing the admin foreign key in the users table.

Kindly assist!

Comment: Id and adminId are not the same. Could you please add some more example how the admin looks like and when you would like to save user - which admin you would like to use? (I think `user.setAdmin(admin);` is what you are looking for as java side you have admin field in user)

Comment: Have editted my question. Will like to use an admin of 1. That is referencing the first admin in the admin row

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get the Admin entity with id 1 first and then set it on the new User:

```
    @Transactional
    public void save(User user) {
        Admin admin = getSession.createQuery("from Admin a where a.id = ?)
                                .setParameter(0, 1);
        user.setAdmin(admin);
        getSession().save(user);
    }
```

Comment: Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.

Comment: Ok, just use named parameters, anyway, did getting the Admin entity solve your problem?

Comment: It is returning NULL on the adminId field of the users table, when I try to save a user

Comment: You need to have a user in the Admin table with id 1. Then you will be able to relate it to any user, otherwise, it'll always be null.

Comment: Yes I do. I have entered an admin manually into the admin table with an id of 1

Comment: Does  Admin admin = getSession.createQuery return the entity or null?

Comment: It returns the entity

Comment: Do you have @Transactional in the save method (or at class level)?

Comment: Yes. can you please check this thread.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588879/insert-a-value-of-1-on-users-table-that-is-referencing-admin-table-hibernate

Comment: If I remove the nullable annotation it inserts null but adding it, it throws exception in trying ton insert into a user